# Ruby - method parameters

Tags: ruby

My method:

```
def my_method=(attributes, some_option = true, another_option = true)
  puts hello
end
```

When i try to call this, i get such error:

```
my_method=({:one => 'one', :two => 'two'}, 1, 1)
#you_code.rb:4: syntax error, unexpected ',', expecting ')'
#my_method=({:one => 'one', :two => 'two'}, 1, 1)
                                      ^
```

What's the problem?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Method with suffix punctuation `=` can have only one argument.

Otherwise, you must use `send` to invoke with multiple parameters.

```
send :'my_method=', {:a => 1}, 1, 1
```

Comment: And what do you think about this [rails attributes= method](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Base.html#method-i-attributes-3D) ?

Comment: @VladimirTsukanov and also "The guard_protected_attributes argument is now deprecated"

Answer (score 0):

Don't use parenthesis when invoking a method using the `=` syntactic sugar.

Invoke it like this:

`mymethod= {:one => 'one', :two => 'two'}, 1, 1`